# How to remove multiple strings from beginning of another string using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I need to remove multiple strings like `www`, `ww2`, `www3` from the beginning of a string.

For example if the string is `www3testme` then I need to remove the `www3` and get the `testme` only.

Below is the code I'm using but it's not working somehow.

```
$str = "www3testabc";
$str = mb_ereg_replace("^(www|www3|ww2)", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

It gives "3testabc" instead of "testabc".

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**I want to use `mb_ereg_replace()` function only.**

Comment: Please let know if you have control over the alternatives or you get them dynamically, and please also explain why you can't use `preg_replace` that also works fine with Unicode strings.

Comment: @Brian, a bansal, could you please check my answer if it is helpful or not? Having a negative score on an accepted answer will disorient future visitors, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(www|www3|ww2)` pattern contains an unanchored alternation group. Since the `www`, the first branch, matches `www` in `www3testabc`, the `www3` is not even tested against, the regex grabs `www` and removes it. Thus, the number remains.

See [**Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager).

You need to sort the alternatives from the longest to shortest (like `^(www3|www2|www)`), or, in your case, it is much more convenient to match `www` at the start of the string with 0+ digits and use

```
$str = "www3testabc";
$str = mb_ereg_replace("^www[0-9]*", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ZDPI2).

**NOTE** You may use a `preg_replace`, too:

```
$str = preg_replace("/^www[0-9]*/u", "", $str);
```

The `/^www[0-9]*/u` regex will remove `www` and then any 0+ digits and will correctly handle Unicode input due to `/u` UNICODE modifier.

Note that if you have no control over the `www`, `www2` etc. strings, and you build the pattern dynamically, you need to sort the strings by length in a descending order and then `implode`.

Comment: I think your answer is fine!

Answer (score 0):

`www3testabca` matches `www` first. Changing order to

```
$str = mb_ereg_replace("^(www3|www|ww2)", "", $str);
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `www3testabc` satisfies both www3 & www, but www string is mentioned earlier. Swap strings inside brackets, so longer string will be first & it should be working.

```
$str = "www3testabc";
$str = mb_ereg_replace("^(www3|ww2|www)", "", $str);
echo $str;
```